# Trying to create Retry object from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

I'm relatively new to Spring-Boot + resilience4j and I'm trying to create a Retry object using the config in my .yml file. Currently I'm trying to decorate a Mono with very similar syntax to what is given in the docs:

```
Retry retry = Retry.of("backendName", sampleRetryConfig);
Mono.fromCallable(backendService::doSomething)
    .transformDeferred(RetryOperator.of(retry))
```

In the above code snippet I'm explicitly declaring the sampleRetryConfig in the code and using that to create my Retry, but is there a way for me to create the Retry object using the RetryConfig pulled from my .yml file?

```
resilience4j.retry:
instances:
    apiRetry:
        maxAttempts: 3
        waitDuration: 2s
        enableExponentialBackoff: true
        ignoreExceptions:
            - example.exceptions
```

Support seems to be there for using the @Retry annotation, but I haven't found anything about support for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: are you simply want to do a Retry or it has to be using resilience4j ?

Comment: @Raj It needs to be done using resilience4j

Comment: I have not used it ever, check this if it can help you to achieve this https://reflectoring.io/retry-with-springboot-resilience4j/

Comment: Hello, have you tried using @value annotation to inject the retry properties in your code from the yaml file? If not see this doc https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer but here's what I ended up doing. Using the RetryRegistry and declaring the Retry objects as beans I was able to make it work.
Here's the contents of the .yml

```
resilience4j:
  retry:
      api-path:
        maxAttempts: 1
        waitDuration: 1s
        ignoreExceptions:
```

And the class where the retry beans were created:

```
private final RetryRegistry retryRegistry;

@Bean
public Retry apiPathRetry() {
    return retryRegistry.retry("api-path");
}
```

Then finally, using the objects in a class.

```
return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> method) 
.flatMap(genericData-> {business logic})
.transformDeferred(RetryOperator.of(apiPathRetry));
```